# how to set up a constant import root path?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a big project with lots of folders:

```
...
|
--- components
| |
| --- c1
| | |
| | --- c11
| --- c2
--- models
| |
| --- m1
--- services
  |
  --- s1
```

eg in `c11`, how i currently import `m1` is to use `../../models/m1`. But this is dreadful because in the future if the folder structure changes, I have to change the relative path too. What I want is something like `my-models/m1` where `my-models` is defined somewhere in some way. And if there is a future change, I only need to change its definition instead of each individual importing module.

Can anyone please give me some suggestions on this?

Comment: Any modern development software will take care of renaming the paths for you in each files of your project.

Comment: @Ploppy It is not about renaming but structural changes. What if I create another folder under `c1` and move `c11` into it?

Answer (score 1):

this medium article will solve your problems :

[Absolute imports with React](https://medium.com/@ktruong008/absolute-imports-with-create-react-app-4338fbca7e3d)

Comment: Do Not Post Links Only! Little Description from the link is appreciated.